# alternative solution to asking user to create a new table

Tags: ms-access

I use access to store concert registration information at the non-profit I currently work at.  I have it set up so that I dump all of the patron contact information into one table, and all of the concert registration information into another.  when we change our concert season, I simply copy/paste the "2012-13 concert registration table" and rename it the "2013-14" concert registration table".

the concert registration table serves as my "hub" for all my other information.  I have about a half-dozen summary queries that show information for specific concerts, who I still need to collect payment for etc. as well as many Word mail merges associated with each document. This setup works great, except that every season I need to go in and re-link all of the queries and word docs to the new registration table

I will be leaving my job at the end of next month, and I would like to make the database more user-friendly, especially since I am fairly certain that my replacement will have zero familiarity with access.  my questions are:

1) Is there a more elegant, easy way to transition from season to season other than to create a new registration table and subsequent queries from year-to-year?

2) How can I idiot-proof this database for the new person when I'm gone?  I'm scared that if I create an extensive "how-to" guide, it simply won't be read and the person will be forced to reinvent the wheel.  I'm toying with creating a switchboard, but I'm scared that this will make the database seem more unapproachable.

Thank you for your insight, happy to clarify if there are any questions!

Answer (score 1):

Just make 1 table. Call it "registration table" and add a new field called Season.  Your queries will be include a filter for that field. Then you won't need to relink your queries, copy tables, etc.

For an example, say you have a query to pull all the information from that table for a particular season. It might look something like:

```
 Select * from RegistrationTable where Season=[What Season];
```

When run, the query will prompt the user for the season and pull only that data.

Also, I do recommend the "how-to" guide. There's probably a lot of manual manipulation of the database that you do and don't even think about. And if nothing else, you can always say you gave them documentation and thus provided for your successor.

Comment: I agree. Doing different table will get (is already?) really cumbersome. One table, include season and away you go.

You should do this also for registration so people don't have to keep re-registering.

Comment: thank you, that actually makes a lot of sense.  I figured I would just make a drop down table with the next 20 years worth of seasons, and hopefully by that time there will be a better solution in place anyway...

Comment: one additional question, should does it make sense to allow multiple field values for the "season" field?  I don't want someone since these patrons register for differentamounts of tickets each season, I think it makes sense to create a new record for each patron every season, even if they are returning members

Comment: I agree. One record per patron per season. So if the patron has been a member for 5 years, he/she should have 5 unique records, one for each season.